# trying to get VB.NET to call IronPython to increment a VB variable

Tags: vb.net, ironpython

Can't get IronPython called by VB to return an incremented integer.
Value returned is same as passed to IronPython.

I want my VB.NET windows forms app to pass a variable 123 to IronPython, have IronPython add 10 to the variable, then have VB  fetch it back.
But, it comes back still 123.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.Scripting
Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting


Public Class Form1
     Private Sub Button_GO_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_GO.Click
         ' HELLO WORLD...
         ' bring up an IronPython runtime 
        dim engine = Python.CreateEngine()
        dim  scope = engine.CreateScope()  

        ' create a source tree from code '
        dim source =  engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("print 'hello from python'")
        ' run the script in the IronPython runtime'
        source.Execute(scope)

        ' MODIFY VARIABLE: BUG:  returns 1 instead of 11'
        engine = Python.CreateEngine()
        scope = engine.CreateScope()  

        ' create a Python variable "i" with the value 1'            
        scope.SetVariable( "i", 1 )

        ' this script will simply add 1 to it '
        source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString( "i += 10" )

        ' pull the value back out of IronPython and display it:'
        dim response = scope.GetVariable("i")
        debug.print(     response ) 
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.  Behold....

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.Scripting
Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting


Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' VB SENDS A VARIABLE TO IRONPYTHON, WHICH INCS AND RETURNS IT......             http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/scripting_ironpython_dlr
       '/* bring up an IronPython runtime */  
        dim engine = Python.CreateEngine()
        dim  scope = engine.CreateScope()  




        ' create a Python variable "i" with the value 1         
        scope.SetVariable( "i", 123 )



        ' this script will simply add 1 to it 
        dim source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString( "i += 10" )

        '/* run the script in the IronPython runtime */  
        source.Execute(scope)


       '     /* pull the value back out of IronPython and display it */
            Console.WriteLine(scope.GetVariable("i").ToString())

End Sub
```

End Class